# Empty component for child routing purposes

Tags: routes, angular

How exactly can I create a child route that doesn't automatically navigate to its route?

I have a navigation component that navigates to various modules in my application. One of the modules that I navigate to, let's call it catalog, has its own child route to show the details of a particular object. I want to navigate just to catalog, and not to catalog/details. Only when I click on a particular object in the catalog, do I want to navigate to catalog/details.

So on my navigation component, I have the initial route defined.

```
            new Route({ path: "/reporting/catalog/...", 
                        component: ReportCatalogComponent, 
                        name: "Reporting.Catalog" }),
```

In its template, is the `[routerLink]`.

```
<a class="navbar-link" [routerLink]="['Reporting.Catalog', 'Default']">Report Catalog</a>
```

Inside of `ReportCatalogComponent` I have the child routes defined

```
@RouteConfig([
    new Route({ path: "/", component: EmptyComponent, name: "Default", useAsDefault: true }),
    new Route({ path: "details/", component: ReportDetailsComponent, name: "Details" })
])
```

I don't want to have that Default path... since it's simply there to circumvent navigating directly to the details page. I have no details selected yet, so I shouldn't navigate there.

Is there a way currently in Angular2 for me to set that child route, but not have it instantly navigate there? Or even if I have to have a second route defined as I do, is there a way to not have to create an EmptyComponent that I assign to the route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you swap components I believe you'll get what you want:

```
new Route({ path: "/reporting/catalog/...", component: EmptyComponent, name: "Reporting.Catalog" }),

@RouteConfig([
    new Route({ path: "/", component: ReportCatalogComponent, name: "Default", useAsDefault: true }),
    new Route({ path: "details/", component: ReportDetailsComponent, name: "Details" })
])
```

You might have to add `template: "<router-outlet></router-outlet>"` to the `EmptyComponent`...

Comment: This seems so hackey though. Is this an irregular design, or should this be something that is pretty straightforward in the routing package?

Comment: I think you just have to get used to the idea that RoutingComponent (component with RouteConfig) is different then ViewComponent (that renders particular route)...